# Is there a single word meaning "something which stops something"?

Tags: single-word-requests

A trigger is something which causes something to start, e.g. caffeine and stress can be triggers for palpitations. Is there an opposite noun, a single word meaning "something which causes something to stop?" E.g. "Exercise can be a [thing which stops/mitigates/reduces] palpitations."

Comment: Do you want a verb or a noun?

Comment: I'm looking for a noun. The closest I can think of is an inhibiting factor or mitigating factor.

Comment: Uh, how about a "stop"?

Comment: a "stopper", not to be confused with a "block" that blocks something.

Comment: @vectory - *Stopper* has a specific, special meaning.  You put it in the drain of a sink or bathtub to prevent the water from flowing out.

Comment: @aparente001 its hard to imagine that that's what *show-stopper* came from. Quite the opposite, actually, a "block" as I alluded to is a thing that does nothing. I should have squared "blocker" with "stopper".

Comment: @vectory - I don't understand what you're trying to communicate to me.  For example, what do you want to convey with this "square" phrase? // Well, a stopper in a bathtub *stops* the flow of water.  What I'm trying to let you know is that when an English speaker sees the word "stopper," they are not going to think "show-stopper."  They are going to think of the bathtub.

Comment: We need at least one sample sentence and context the word will be used in.

Comment: "*8. To accord or agree exactly; to be consistent with; to suit; to fit. quotations ▲
(Can we date this quote?) Cowper
No works shall find acceptance […] that square not truly with the Scripture plan.*" (en.wiktionary.org/wiki/square). You'll also find *stopper* right where it should be. Although I was being sarcastic, no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

The scientific biological terms would be:

> [**inhibitor**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inhibitor) (noun), inhibit (verb)

or in pharmacology (as you mention caffeine)

> [**antagonist**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/antagonist) (noun), antogonize (verb)

although this latter tends to be used in relation to specific biological components, rather than an overall process.

In general speech there are several verbs that you could use, but perhaps fewer nouns. Possibilities that occur are:

> [**block**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/block) (on)
>
> [**preventive**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/preventive) (against)

But if you have heart palpitations I would see a doctor before exercising.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/inhibitor

> **Inhibitor**
>
> An inhibitor is a substance or material that slows down or halts some
>   activity. This word is popular in the chemistry lab, but you might
>   also hear it at a garage. ... Different substances are inhibitors for
>   different reactions and activities. Think of an inhibitor as
>   chemistry's way of saying "Slow down!" or "Stop!"

If you then look up synonyms for 'inhibitor', there will be many more options.

Answer (score 0):

The word DETERRENT can be used dictionary meaning of which is something " preventing something from happening" and can be used both as an adjective or noun

deterrent (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deterrent)
Pronunciation
- (British) IPA: /dɪˈtɛɹənt/
Adjective
1. Serving to deter, preventing something from happening.

Noun

deterrent (plural deterrents)

1. Something that deters.

Comment: Please include a link.

Answer (score 0):

"Ender". "destroyer", "preventionist" (just made that up, but I like it), "abolitionist", the list goes on. It would help to see this in context. Can you show us how you want to use it? Does this word have to refer to something that stops everything (such a word I don't think exists) or something that stops a certain subset of things? Additionally, if it's the latter, does that thing have to stop those other things as a matter of course, or can it choose not to? ("Executive" would be an example of this.)

Answer (score -1):

A **brake** causes something to slow down or stop.

**brake**  [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/brake)

> something used to **slow down** or **stop** movement or activity

Your example sentence, though I am not sure of its veracity, would be:

> "Exercise can act as a break to palpitations/anxiety."

Comment: Hmm.  You want *break* or *brake*?  They're different.

Comment: figurative and literal use of the noun break